# How to get Option field value in Request in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to update my foem, and I have `Country` value in dropdown and I want to get this value in request, so that i can update my form using this value in `request`, Please check my code and let me know where I am mistaking.

Here is my `test.html` file...

```
<select name='country'>
  <option>Select One</option>
   {% for countries in country %}
  <option value="{{country.id}}" {% if countries.id == datas.country_id %}selected{% endif 
   %}>{{countries.country}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
datas = MyModelName.objects.get(pk=id)
  if request.method == "POST"
    datas.country = request.POST.get('country')
    datas.save()
```

it's not selecting the country, it's giving me error, Please guide me how i can solve this issue.

Comment: What's the error? Along with code show how you are rendering the values to template / html file. Could be issue of typo.

Comment: you forgot ":" in your if satement in views.py
it should be
if request.method == "POST":

Answer (score 0):

you better use ModelForm to edit data in your models, it allows you to check all entered values in more clean way

create ModelForm to edit your data

```
class MyModelNameEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModelName
```

then in your views.py you can do this:

```
datas = MyModelName.objects.get(pk=id)
if request.POST:
    edit_form = MyModelNameEditForm(request.POST, instance=datas)
    if edit_form.is_valid(): 
        edit_form.check()
else:
    edit_form = MyModelNameEditForm(instance=datas)

# don't forget to send your form as a parameter to your template
return render(request, "path_to_template/test.html", {'edit_form': edit_form})
```

then in your test.html you can replace:

```
<select name='country'>
  <option>Select One</option>
   {% for countries in country %}
  <option value="{{country.id}}" {% if countries.id == datas.country_id %}selected{% endif 
   %}>{{countries.country}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

with one line

```
{{ edit_form.country }}
```

you can read more about `ModelForm` in official docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform